# Retrieving printer toner information with pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am trying to retrieve printer toner information from networked printers.

I found the following reference record for printer supplies -> http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11 (OID = prtMarkerSupplies)

I tried integrating the OID in the following code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

iterator = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
    UdpTransportTarget(('here goes ip of a printer', 161)),
    ContextData(),

    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', "prtMarkerSupplies", 0))
)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)


if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)

elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))

else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

The above code returns:

```
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: No symbol SNMPv2-MIB::prtMarkerSupplies at <pysnmp.smi.builder.MibBuilder object at 0x000001F8D1FC3D00>
```

How can I retrieve toner information using the SNMP protocol and pysnmp?

Retrieving system information works as intended:

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', "sysDescr", 0))
```

Comment: While you might have found a quick workaround below, you should learn about your mistake. `sysDescr` is defined in the MIB document that contains the module `SNMPv2-MIB`, so that's why `ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', "sysDescr", 0)` is valid. `prtMarkerSupplies`, however, isn't part of `SNMPv2-MIB`, so you should find its actual module name and use that instead. When you perform a WALK operation, PySNMP/PySMI finds out the module/object names for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer from the following thread -> [snmpwalk with PySNMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000319/snmpwalk-with-pysnmp)

Instead of iterating over getCmd, I used SNMP walk to walk through all of the OIDs.